# get magento order collection with different field values for the same field

Tags: php, magento, collections

Hi I want to get order collection with multiple field values for same field.Already I tried to get the collections with addFieldToFilter for individual field values('status':pening & 'status':processing) and I merged both the collecions to a single collection.Now I'm getting problem like I can't able to access the resulted collection, its troughs error like getMethod can't call on non object.Give me any suggestions.

Here is my code :

```
$shippedCollection = array();
$processingCollection = array();
$orderSCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$shippedCollection = $orderSCollection->addFieldToFilter('status','delivered_carrier');
$orderPCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$processingCollection = $orderPCollection->addFieldToFilter('status','processing');
$order = array_merge($shippedCollection->getAllIds(),$processingCollection->getAllIds());

$order->getData('increment_id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('delivered_carrier','pending')));
echo count($order_collection->getAllIds());
```